# status ufw problem (exited)

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have a problem with the ufw (firewall) program that is running, but status is "Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-13 14:56:25 +0330; 31min ago" can anyone help me the reason?

Comment: That sounds normal (it is a systemd oneshot service). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Not! normal status is like "Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-13 22:45:40 +0330; 3s ago" :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

> Services declared as oneshot are expected to take some action and exit immediatelly (thus, they are not really services, no running processes remain). A common pattern for these type of service is to be defined by a setup and a teardown action.

Source: [source link for the description with an example](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/d006f12914b21198ee43)

For me there is one imprntant option in my "ufw" file:

```
[Unit]
**Before**=network.target
```

So I assume it is run ONLY **before** network is loaded. After that it can't be run. And as it is a "oneshot" unit, that is why it works just like that.

[here is my ufw systemd file contents on Debian 9.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33ATz.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ufw service just loads settings into iptables, so it has no ongoing tasks to do. You can see that it is working by running the command `dmesg` or if you want a live stream of the blocks, `watch dmesg`